# Terrible texturing mistake

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I made a temple in blender but when I textured it, I didn't actually use UV maps or materials. My textures will show in texture mode, but not when rendered. Will I have to retexture everything all over again? thanks

Comment: What render engine? *How* did you texture it? Because there is no way to texture an object without a material. If you have no material that is why the texture is not rendering.

Comment: you are correct. I simply marked a seam along a piece of my temple, unwrapped it, and applied a texture to the unwrapped piece. I know why it's not rendering but I need to know how to fix it

Comment: "I simply marked a seam along a piece of my temple, unwrapped it" so you used UV maps. In order to fix texture not rendering add material and make it using UV map.